# SQLAlchemy Update row where session has gone out of scope

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, updates

I have an existing get method.

```
    def get_parameter(self, app, my_business_key):
        my_db = MultiTenantSQLAlchemy(app)
        session = my_db.get_session(app)
        return session.query(MyParameter).filter(MyParameter.my_business_key.in_(my_business_key)).all()
```

Since I don't have the primary key and I'm updating by a business key, my assumption is that I have to pull the records first.

I get the parameters object, do the updates to it and then want to save them.

```
    def save_parameters(self, app, my_business_key, my_parameters):
        my_db = MultiTenantSQLAlchemy(app)
        session = lro_db.get_session(app)

        # session.Update(my_parameters)    ?????

        session.flush()
        session.commit()
```

Every example I find on here shows creating the session, doing the select, doing the update, then flush/commit all in one method. I'd rather not duplicate the GET if I don't have to.

Ideally I'd love for this to all be one singular query like bulk_update_mappings and only go to the DB once but I don't think I can do that without the primary key.

Comment: If you have many objects, you can collect (primary) keys in one round-trip, and do an update a second round-trip. Is your business key unique enough for the update? If not, how would you choose which record with the same business key to update?

Comment: Business key is unique. It's an id that stays consistent across multiple customers databases. X parameter will always have my_business_key of 20. Y parameter will always have my_business_key of 21.

UPDATE My_Parameters
SET Stuff = Value
WHERE My_Business_Key = 20

would update one record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the table directly, do not fetch / update / save instances if you don't have to.

```
my_table = MyORMClass.__table__
update_statement = (
    my_table.update()
            .where(my_table.c.business_key == bindparam('key'))
            .values(field_to_set=bindparam('value')))
session.execute(update_statement, [
    {'key': 100, 'value': 'value for 100'},
    {'key': 200, 'value': 'value for 200'},
])
```

Here the update happens in one round-trip.

the idea is that you use `bindparam` to bind your data to named placeholders, and then pass a list of dicts where keys match the names of the placeholders. In this case, it's `'key'` and `'value'`, but it can be anything, and of course you can use many arguments in `.values()`. The example assumes that the business key field is named `business_key` in your table, and the field you want to update is named `field_to_set`.

Please note the difference between `.where()` ans `.values()`: one takes a condition formed by column object and `==`, the other takes plain named arguments.

Of course you can build the update list programmatically, I just show a constant here for simplicity.

See [this SQLAlchemy doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#inserts-updates-and-deletes) for reference.

Comment: Ok. I had seen that in other answers but it looked wrong. Felt hackey... Like it was bypassing the ORM models. But there it is in the docs...

Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Justinwilliams: It's not a 'hack' but a departure from the ORM land. ORM is great when you have few objects, and working with a separate object (representing a DB row) is what you mostly do. When you have to update  things in bulk, the abstraction becomes too costly. But you can avoid it by working on a lower level, directly with tables. Frankly, I more often work with tables and queries and don't use the object mapping; it's perfectly adequate for many tasks. OTOH you still have nice composable query objects, conditions, etc, instead of raw SQL.